# Как изменить названия папок dist и src в WebPack

Tags: webpack

Я хочу поменять названия папок src и dist на названия dev и public. Но, когда я меняю названия этих папок, а также делаю соответствующие правки в файле webpack.config.js, то у меня перестает работать плагин ExtractTextPlugin. Вопрос, как мне грамотно настроить webpack.config.js, чтобы при этом плагин ExtractTextPlugin продолжал работать?

webpack.config.js:

```
let path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

let conf = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    devServer: {
        overlay: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                //exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    //fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
                /*
                use: [ 
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ] */
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    ]
};

module.exports = (env, options) => {
    let mode = options.mode ==='production';

    conf.devtool = mode ?  false //'source-map' 
                        : 'eval-sourcemap';
    return conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все проблема решена. Я создал новую папку, скинул в нее уже созданные папки dev и public. В эту же папку я скинул webpack.config.js и package.json. Потом в консоле прописал команду "npm i". И после этого все нормально заработало